# apply different css class every 3 ul with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, loops

I have a lot of li's and I am looping through them and wrapping in groups of 5 but I need to apply a different class to every 3 groups so it looks like this

```
<ul class="class1"><li></li><li></li> <li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
<ul class="class2"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  
<ul class="class3"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  

<ul class="class1"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  
<ul class="class2"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  
<ul class="class3"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>    

<ul class="class1"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  
<ul class="class2"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>  
<ul class="class3"><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
```

I am using this to group them

```
var lis = $(".leftHover ul li");  
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=5) { 
  is.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll(<ul></ul>);  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> apply different css class every 3 ul
>   with jquery

You can use the [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector like this:

```
$(".leftHover ul li:nth-child(3n)").addClass('className');
```

That will add class to **every** third `<li>` under the element with class `leftHover`. You can off course change the argument of `3` to whatever you wish for your requirements.

Comment: I think he wants classes applied to the `<ul>s` and not the `<li>s`. That's just a simple matter of changing the selector though.

@Tom: Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/ukGJp/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do ..

```
var lis = $(".leftHover ul li");  
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=5) { 
  lis.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<ul class="class' + (i%3) + '"></ul>');  
}
```

That will name them the other way around .. class2, class1, class0. To get them as class1, class2, class3. You can just change `(i%3)` to `(3-(i%3))`.